# Evaluating workbooks with microsoft-graph / office 365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to upload a workbook to office365, have it evaluated, and then download the evaluated workbook?

By evaluation I mean have all the formulas in all the cells be calculated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly [upload](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_put_content) the workbook using OneDrive API. You can then access workbook content using [Excel REST](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel) API and read/write/calc. I'm not sure what you mean by evaluate. The `eval` Excel API itself is not supported. Please update the question with exact requirements for the community to help you.

Comment: By evaluation I mean have all the formulas in all the cells be calculated. Is that possible to do in Microsoft's cloud environment before redownloading the file?